# SQL Regex function returning wrong Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have formed an sql query  to check if value in email field is blank or not and Valid so if suppose if value in that column is blank then 
 it is returning proper value but if the value is not in proper format then it is not returning noproperformat@format.com. So if value is test@test.com.in then it is invalid format can anyone please help with this query.

```
select  Case  
    when idfEmail!='' then idfEmail 
    when (idfEmail LIKE '%_@__%.__%.__'
        AND PATINDEX('%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,\-]%', idfEmail) = 0) then 'noproperformat@format.com'
    else('noemailfound@noemail.com') end as idfEmail from mytable order by idfEmail Desc
```

When i am running below query then i am getting all invalid emails.

```
SELECT   idfEmail
FROM wp.APAddress
WHERE idfEmail  LIKE '%_@__%.__%.__'
AND PATINDEX('%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,\-]%', idfEmail) = 0
```

Comment: `when idfEmail!='' then idfEmail` catches all emails that are `<> ''`. After that the next `when` has no chance to run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does SQL Server CASE statement evaluate all conditions or exit on first TRUE condition?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/43352/5203)

Comment: Thanks @Gserg your suggestion worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
 select  Case  
  when (idfEmail!='' and idfEmail Not LIKE '%_@__%.__%.__' ) then idfEmail 
  when (idfEmail LIKE '%_@__%.__%.__'
        AND PATINDEX('%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,\-]%', idfEmail) = 0) then 'noproperformat@format.com'
  else('noemailfound@noemail.com') end as idfEmail from mytable order by idfEmail Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when idfEmail like '%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,\-]%' 
             then 'noproperformat@format.com'
             when idfEmail is not null
             then idfEmail
             else 'noemailfound@noemail.com'
        end) as idfEmail
from mytable
order by idfEmail desc;
```

A `case` expression evaluates the conditions in order.  Your first condition basically matches all non-NULL emails, so the first condition is returned.